# Fetching multiple event details in Office 365

Tags: rest, calendar, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I need to fetch information related to eventId from office 365 for multiple events.

Is there a way I can get that info in a single REST call?
I want specific events only (based on **eventId's** only)

Answer (score 1):

A batch request may be what you are looking for.

See [json Batching Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) for more information

Keep in mind that batching is currently limited to 20 requests per message ([known issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues))

**Example:**

You will need to send a POST Message to the batch endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
```

inside the body you will need to include your requests:
Note: do not include the server url (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/) in the url property or the request will fail with "BadRequest - Invalid request Uri".

Request-Body:

```
  {
      "requests": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2018-03-01T18:31:34.206Z&enddatetime=2018-03-12T18:31:34.206Z"
        },
                {
          "id": "2",
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "/me/events/{someEventId}"
        },
      ]
}
```

When the server has processed all requests an response array containing the results will be sent back:

Server-Response:

```
  {
    "responses": [
            {
        "id": "2",
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "OData-Version": "4.0",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8",
            "ETag": "W/\"Z+ICSvkiAfZX7XWQAZ6IH==\""
        },
        "body": {
           // the event object
        }
    },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                "OData-Version": "4.0",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
            },
            "body": {
                "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('aUserID')/calendarView",
                "value": [
                  // list of  found event-objects
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```